# Angular redirect/break page after manual refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made simple angular application with simple routing.

```
angular.module("mainApp", ["ngRoute"]);

angular.module("mainApp")
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
     .when("/main", {
         templateUrl: "views/main.html",
         controller: "MainController"
     })
     .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/main" });
});
```

Start "mongoose-free-6.1" server, and first time when I open my page everything works fine. My main page path is:

```
http://192.168.0.16:8080/EventManagementMobile/EventManagementMobile/#/main
```

After first manual refresh on the page I get route:

```
http://192.168.0.16:8080/main#/main
```

Page is broken and in console I get error:

```
GET http://192.168.0.16:8080/views/main.html 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function)
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$compile/tpload?p0=views%2Fmain.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
at Error (native)
```

The same happens when I start it from VS2015 in IISExpress. First route work fine:

I probably do not understand how routing works. What happens here ?

Comment: This is a very confusing problem. I would be very happy to help if you could show more code. Or even MUCH Better a Plunker/codepen/JSFiddle Representation!

Comment: Code is simple, just empty page and empty controller. I think that problem is in server. When I start server it starts on path: http://192.168.0.16:8080/. After it I browse to the my EventManagementMobile application trough the browser and that is ok. Every next refresh back me to the start server page, and angular just add "/main" on path and I get wrong path. I will try to reproduce in plunker, but I doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by synfusion library loaded on page together with angular. Answer from synfusion support team:

> The script file ej.mobile.all.min.js is a collection of Essential
>   Studio JavaScript Mobile components. In that, AppView acts as a base
>   container and master page for the Mobile application. We have handled
>   the history navigation internally for Single Page Applications, which
>   interfere for Angular routing. Hence for Angular routing, we need to
>   prevent the initialization of AppView. Refer to the following code
>   example.
>
> ```
> [html]
>
>  <script>
>     App.preventAppviewInit = true
> </script>
> ```
>
> The above mentioned script have to be referred next to
>   ej.mobile.all.min.js script reference.

Link to the original question and answer:

http://www.syncfusion.com/forums/123560/loading-syncfusion-scripts-on-page-break-angular-routing